# Tkinter - How would I go about resetting list of objects?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Yesterday I asked this question [Creating elements by loop Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642039/creating-elements-by-loop-tkinter) to find out how to dynamically create some bullet points. Now I'm looking to add a clear button so when pressed, will reset the entire form. I have tried setting the list back to [] but it didn't work.

edit - So basically when I press reset I'd like it to look exactly like it did when the form was loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The buttons are removed with the `destroy` method:

```
    for button in self.button:
        button.destroy()
```

---

```
import Tkinter as tk

class ButtonBlock(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.button = []
        self.button_val = tk.IntVar()
        entry = tk.Entry()
        entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
        entry.bind('<Return>', self.onEnter)
        entry.focus()
        clear_button = tk.Button(master, text='Clear', command=self.onClear)
        clear_button.grid(row=0, column=1)
    def onClear(self):
        for button in self.button:
            button.destroy()
    def onEnter(self, event):
        entry = event.widget
        num = int(entry.get())
        self.onClear()
        for i in range(1, num+1):
            self.button.append(tk.Radiobutton(
                self.master, text=str(i), variable=self.button_val, value=i,
                command=self.onSelect))
            self.button[-1].grid(sticky='WENS', row=i, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
    def onSelect(self):
        print(self.button_val.get())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    ButtonBlock(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the list back (i.e. using `self.button = []`) just clears the data stored in the `button` variable. That action alone is not connected to the user interface (UI). You have to explicitly remove the widget objects which were created (by the `onEnter` method).

So the clearing feature you are looking for should be feasible by extending the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15642635/404469) from your previous question. Add an `onClear` method to the `ButtonBlock` class so that when your "Clear" control (i.e. using a button widget) is selected its callback function calls `ButtonBlock.onClear()`, similar to how your `Entry` widget invokes the `onEnter` method.

**EDIT**: See unutbu's answer to this question. When selected, the `clear_button` control calls `ButtonBlock.onClear()`. The for loop in `onClear` gets a reference to each button ojbect from the `button` list and calls the object's `destroy` method, which removes it from the UI.